# How to quickly or bulk add items to a Visual Studio project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix, envdte

I have a visual studio extension that needs to add a large number of files to my project (~50,000)
I am using EnvDTE.Project.ProjectItems to manipulate the project
Using AddFromFile is very slow (>30 minutes to complete)
I can not use AddFromDirectory because the directories contain files that should be excluded

Is there another function that I should be using?
Do I need manipulate the project XML directly and reload the project?

Comment: *Do I need manipulate the project XML directly and reload the project?* most likely. But from my perspective I'd start by strongly questioning why a single project should track 50k individual files, looking for a better way.

Comment: Are you suggesting I split it into multiple projects? That would not actually speed up the solution generation time would it? They are all source files that I would like to be tracked in a centralized place.